# Use laptops monitor on another computer

Tags: vga, monitor

I just bought a new pc, but i dont have a monitor yet. Is it posible to use my old laptops (omnibook 3000) monitor with VGA cable?

Added:

Options

1. Old PC working as a PC - just connect somehow - not relevant to this forum
2. Using screen form old PC, and anything else from old PC that may be needed, is there something I can build that will allow this equipment to work as a "VGA" monitor. This seems wholly relevant to this site.

Comment: This site for electrical and electronics design questions, and your question is unfortunately off-topic. You might try posting it on the [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)stackexchange site.

Comment: It may be on topic if you would try to create an interface for interfacing the monitor to the VGA cable; unfortunately, it's quite difficult as the manufacturer rarely give the datasheet of the monitors

Comment: As @clabacchio said, I don't think it's practical with a VGA cable.  I was steering you over to SuperUser where they might suggest solutions like [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.org/), however that solution would require you to borrow a monitor briefly to set up the software on the desktop to begin with.

Comment: @tcrosley VNC requires the laptop to be working and adds some lag (because of the network). It also will result in problems if the headless computer cannot boot. On the other hand, somehow adding a DVI->LCD interface could make the monitor more useful.

Comment: @Pentium100, the OP never mentioned the laptop(s) were not working.  A network connection using a crossover cable should not have a noticeable delay.  I use [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/) between two computers located 20 miles apart and the delay is hardly noticeable.  Once I had it all set up, I could reboot the remote computer and log back on without any problems.

Comment: @tcrosley While there is no noticeable delay for regular work, watching a movie or playing a game over remote control connection may not be as good as doing it with a directly connected monitor. As for reboot, I mentioned boot problems - without special hardware you cannot, for example, go into CMOS setup on the remote PC or boot in safe mode.

Comment: LCD Monitors separated form their laptop host come can come in a handful of connection schemes. There are many vendors of OEM LCD Controllers that can connect almost any computer source (VGA, HDMI, DVI, etc..) to LCD source. You'll probably have to determine the type of connectors (Video and Backlight) to be successful.

Comment: @Liukas, if all you need is a temporary monitor with a VGA interface, you can probably get a used 17" CRT monitor for under $20 at a garage sale, since most people have abandoned them for LCD screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a working monitor from notebook parts is rather difficult, but doable.

The notebook hardware itself is not meant to do video input on the VGA jack. You will have to bypass the old hardware.

As others pointed out, if your notebook still boots, you might want to use it as a thin station. Try [thinstation.org](http://thinstation.org/)

Here is what I know about building an actual monitor from notebook parts:

So far, I did not hook up a full display - I only used the backlight.

There are two major tasks: Getting the power supply for the backlight working, and getting the video signal transported to the display.

Most notebooks use a LVDS bus to connect the video driver to the display.

HP probably did not manufacture the display themselves. In some cases I was able to identify the original make of the display and get hold of a datasheet for it, for instance with a rather old MPC Notebook.

The backlight power supply can also be difficult. Your best bet is to reverse engineer the notebook, identify the high voltage converter, measure its supply voltage. Take care not to get in contact with the high voltage, which is a few hundred Volts at a few mA. Something like 330 V, 4 mA on the last one I played with.

In notebooks, the HV supply tends to be a separate assembly.

There used to be a Kontron device (VGA to LVDS) and several articles about it, but it seems to be discontinued. All the links I had to it are now stale. (mp3car et al)

Most recent builds use FPGA to drive. [FPGA build](http://axio.ms/projects/iiyamameetxilinx/) Another impressive build is here: [beaglelvds](http://axio.ms/projects/beaglelcd/)